# ssh outgoing connections increase limit

Tags: ssh, connection

I am using pssh (https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) to ssh from one Linux machine to several others and start the job there. The ssh connection is terminated only after the job on that instance completes. The problem is there seems to be a limit on the number of outgoing ssh connections from one instance - it is around 30. I searched around and found that the values of MaxStartups and MaxSessions in ssd_config needs to be increased. I did that, but then I got the following error messages.

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 63: Bad configuration option: MaxStartups
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 64: Bad configuration option: MaxSessions
```

I guess those parameters are not supported in the version of ssh on the Linux machine.

I also increased the value of net.core.somaxconn in sysctl.conf to 1024 from the default 128 as was suggested in some posts, but it didn't help.

Posts checked:

- [SSH Connection Limitations](https://superuser.com/questions/266467/ssh-connection-limitations)
- www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.security.ssh/2010-06/msg00031.html
- www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/max-concurrent-ssh-connections-limit-739647/

Answer (score -1):

Pssh has a limit on the number of concurrent ssh sessions. It looks like the default is 32. You can change the limit using the `-p` or `--par` command line argument. See the [pssh manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh).

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 63: Bad configuration option: MaxStartups
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 64: Bad configuration option: MaxSessions
```

`ssh_config` is a configuration file for the ssh *client*, not the server. MaxStartups and MaxSessions are *server* configuration parameters. They go in `sshd_config`, which is the configuration file for the *server*. They also affect incoming sessions, not outgoing sessions.

Comment: Thank you. I did that way, but I still face the same issue -- only 33 ssh connections are possible. I used ssh to connect to 64 machines one after the other without terminating any ssh connection and that worked. I am beginning to suspect pssh rather than ssh.